# Camera2 API Exception on android.media.Image.getPlanes() on certain device

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I use Camera2 API for capturing OCR image in my app (tablet only). Everything is work but there are one device (let's say A Device) didn't work.

Here the log:

```
2021-05-28 13:46:23.402 28882-28937/com. D/OpenGLRenderer: textureCacheSize 75497472
2021-05-28 13:46:23.416 28882-28882/com. I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
2021-05-28 13:46:33.303 28882-28975/com. W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.media.Image$Plane[] android.media.Image.getPlanes()' on a null object reference
2021-05-28 13:46:33.305 28882-28975/com. W/System.err:     at com.Camera2Fragment$6$1.run(Camera2Fragment.java:927)
2021-05-28 13:46:33.307 28882-28975/com. W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
2021-05-28 13:46:33.308 28882-28975/com. W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2021-05-28 13:46:33.310 28882-28975/com. W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2021-05-28 13:46:33.311 28882-28975/com. W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Here my `CaptureSession.CaptureCallback` :

```
CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Bitmap bitmap = null;
                        String nik;

                        try {
                            System.out.println("Array plane : " + mImageReader.acquireLatestImage().getPlanes().toString());
                            ByteBuffer buffer = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage().getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();  // Error start from here, in other device, acquireLatestImage is not null, but in A device is become null
                            byte[] data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                            buffer.get(data);
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            // **In one device, its fall to here**
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        if (bitmap == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to get image, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                         // other my code (proccessing image, ocr and other)
                        }
                    }
               }
         }
 }
```

### Extra

The A device have screen specification 10 inch and 800x1280 and 8MP. I don't know it takes effect for the Surface but it's only happening in this device.

I have read some issues about getting an image from Camera2 API, but actually my code works on many many devices.

Comment: Does A device support Camera2 API? Maybe there are some issues in that GitHub?

Comment: @CoolMind yes it does, the surface is showing up and normal. The surface is stoping to when I click capture button. But I got the exception for A device.

Comment: Should we use `handler.postDelayed()`? How long should be a delay?

Comment: Do you mean delay when open camera? its 2.5 second. But there is no delay between onclick and capturing the image

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Maybe you should move to CameraX or create an issue in https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues. Also maybe you should add a delay between onClick and getting a result.

Comment: Oke no problem, I think there is to much effort to changes the whole structure for one device error. But thank you for the references, I will check it out